# How to override Enterprise Architect default properties Window

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have build a MDG Toolbox. When I drag & drop a class from the toolbox then through a pop-up Window Form (C# addins) I am filling all the Tag Values.

The problem is when I drag & drop a class then only my Window Form is popping up. But when I double click the Class in the diagram then my window form should pop-up instead of default class properties. How to override the default class properties through C#.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the event `EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked` and return `true` to indicate that you have handled the event.

See also the help at http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/ea_oncontextitemdoubleclicked.html

Comment: If it's working, please accept the answer. This shows other users that the problem has a solution, says "thank you" to Geert, and sends him som rep points, all in one.